# With Java 11 RMI calls Slows

Tags: java, rmi, java-11

We have Java application with client Server architecture where client and server communicate with the help of RMI connection.
We have currently used Java 8 it working properly and respond quickly.
But we now planning to move on the Java 11 here also application working properly but comparatively slow as compare to java 8
we took the RMI logs where I can see sun.rmi.transport.DGCImpl_Stub dirty class taking time in Java 11.

**Java 11 RMI logs**

> loadClass FINE: main: name = "java.rmi.server.UID", codebase = "",
>   defaultLoader =
>   jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@4b85612c Nov 21, 2018
>   7:25:12 PM java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2 loadClass FINER: main:
>   class "java.rmi.server.UID" found via defaultLoader, defined by null
>   Nov 21, 2018 7:25:12 PM sun.rmi.transport.DGCImpl_Stub dirty FINE:
>   main: free connection (reuse = true) Nov 21, 2018 7:27:31 PM
>   java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler$MethodToHash_Maps$1  get

**Java 8 RMI logs**

> FINE: main: name = "[B", codebase = "", defaultLoader =
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@d716361 Nov 21, 2018 7:39:29 PM
>   sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler loadClass FINER: main: class "[B" found
>   via defaultLoader, defined by null Nov 21, 2018 7:39:29 PM
>   sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler loadClass FINE: main: name =
>   "java.rmi.server.UID", codebase = "", defaultLoader =
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@d716361 Nov 21, 2018 7:39:29 PM
>   sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler loadClass FINER: main: class
>   "java.rmi.server.UID" found via defaultLoader, defined by null Nov 21,
>   2018 7:39:29 PM sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef done FINE: main: free
>   connection (reuse = true) Nov 21, 2018 7:39:30 PM sun.rmi.server.Util
>   computeMethodHash

Comment: Have you looked at the GC logs? One of the changes in JDK 9 is moving to the G1 collector by default so maybe you could try switching back to the through-put collector to see if it makes a difference in your workload.

Comment: Yes I have checked gc logs but hard luck.